# Spring OIDC with OpenAM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'd like to handle an authorization code grant flow with spring.

It "works" for the redirections, on arriving on my app, correctly redirected to openam, authN and grant authZ, submit, redirected to redirectUri.

But when I come back in the redirectUri, it seems Spring doesn't go inside my method (doesn't stop on my breakpoint), and the security context is probably empty, so not authenticated, so redirected back to auth.

Here's my config, am I missing something ?

REST api in Springboot, with angular frontend

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigOAuth2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/REST/v1/authorization-code/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
                .oauth2Login()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client()
        ;
    }
}
```

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /OAuth2Client

spring:
  application:
    name: OAuth2Client

  security:
    basic:
      enabled: false
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          openam:
            clientId: MyClientId
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code

---

spring:
  profiles: dev

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          openam:
            tokenUri: {openam-dev}/access_token
            authorizationUri: {openam-dev}/authorize
            userInfoUri: {openam-dev}/userinfo
            tokenInfoUri: {openam-dev}/tokeninfo
            jwkSetUri: {openam-dev}/jwk_uri
        registration:
          openam:
            clientSecret: MyClientSecret-dev
            redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/REST/v1/authorization-code/callback"

  logging:
    level:
      org.springframework.security: DEBUG
      org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: DEBUG
```